# How to interpret GLM model results from JMP?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, jmp

I have used normal+identity but not sure how to interpret the results for quality of model.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! // 1) How do you define model quality? // 2) How would you do this assessment in another software?

Comment: I have never used GLM in past. Linear regression used to be measured with R2 and RMSE but here I am not sure what this table and mentioned variable suggesting about the model.